# kivy, on_enter() does not produce any result,

Tags: android, python, mobile, kivy

My current function on kivy needs to display json values from a remote url, 
when when i click to load the Project Screen, those values needs to be loaded there, however Nothing displays.

here is the screen control function:

```
import json
import urllib2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MailScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PrjcScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:5000/api/projects')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        js = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        for k in js:
            layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
            return layout.add_widget(Label(text=js[k]['title']))
class ChatScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GsaMain(BoxLayout):
    pass

class GsamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

GsamApp().run()
```

Here is the kv file

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    IntroScreen:
    MainScreen:
    PrjcScreen:
    MailScreen:
    ChatScreen:

<IntroScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'introscreen'

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0.267, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint: None, None
        width: self.minimum_width  # combined width of child widgets
        height: self.minimum_height # combined height of child widgets
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        spacing: 10

        TextInput:
            id: login
            text: "Login"
            multiline: False
            size_hint: None, None
            height:50
            width: 140
            font_size: 20

        ImgButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'login.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'


<ImgButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0.267, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint: None, None
        width: self.minimum_width  # combined width of child widgets
        height: self.minimum_height # combined height of child widgets
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        spacing: 70

        ProjButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'checkl.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'prjct'

        MsgButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'msgbox.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

        CsCButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'community.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

        CrCButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'Checkmark.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

        ExitButton:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 63
            source: 'exit.png'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

<ProjButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<MsgButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<CrCButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<CsCButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<ExitButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    size_hint: None, None

<MailScreen>:
    name: 'mailscreen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'GSAM Mail'
                font_size: 35
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Chat'
                font_size: 25
                on_release: app.root.current = 'chatscreen'

<ChatScreen>:
    name: 'Discussions'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Chat & Discussions'
                font_size: 35
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Home'
                font_size: 25
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main'

<PrjcScreen>:
    name: 'prjct'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, None
            Label:
                text: 'Community Projects'
                font_size: 35
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'community Projects'
                font_size: 25
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
                GridLayout:
                    id: 'mygrid'
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 4
                    padding: 5
                    spacing: 5
                    Label:
                        text: "Project Title"
                    TextInput:
                        id: ptitle
                    Label:
                        text: "Project Description"
                    TextInput:
                        id: pdescr
```

Can you please help point out what am I not doing right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your on_enter method is *returning* the layout. You actually need to *add* the layout to your screen instead (i.e. it doesn't work in the same way as the build method).

However, once you've done that, you would need to be careful that you don't keep adding a new layout each time.

You might be better off having the layout already defined in your KV file and then just use the on_enter method to clear and (re)populate the grid each time the event is triggered.